# Angular Observable<ObjectModel> services return a string (instead an object of type ObjectModel)

Tags: angular6

here is my service:

```
get(id: string): Observable<PaginaModel> {
    return this.http.get<PaginaModel>('api/pagini/get/' + id);
}
```

the model:

```
import { LinieModel } from "./linie.model";

export class PaginaModel {
    linii: LinieModel[] = [];
}
```

and here how i call it:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('AfisareCanvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.service.get('5b9bad0c457b4e1c70af18f8').subscribe(data =>  {
        console.log(data); //here data is string (like using stringify)
        console.log(data.linii.length); //undefined error 
    });
}
```

i tried using JSON.parse but didnt work.

Comment: what response do you receive?

Comment: @firegloves I got right data but I got as string.. It's like u use JSON. sttingify for an object

Comment: The problem is from service.. I change http request with an of function call and it worked

Comment: Maybe a malformed json that can't be parsed? Or you pass to of function the same data?

Comment: yes..i pass the same data..this is of function call:  return of({linii:[{puncte:[{x:182.5,y:56},{x:182.5,y:56},{x:183.5,y:56},{x:186.5,y:56},{x:193.5,y:56},.....{x:254.5,y:107},{x:266.5,y:123},{x:281.5,y:138},{x:287.5,y:145},{x:289.5,y:149}]}]}); .........and the response from the server is this: "{\"linii\":[{\"puncte\":[{\"x\":182.5,\"y\":56},{\"x\":182.5,\"y\":56},{\"x\":183.5,\"y\":56},{\"x\":186.5,\"y\":56},{\"x\":193.5,\"y\":56},{\"x\":203.5,\"y\":60},.....{\"x\":289.5,\"y\":149}]}]}"

Comment: i found the cause of problem..json from server is was bad..